# image is not displaying

Tags: images

I download envor template. I am using Azura page builder to add or delete an element. There is one menu named "Pages" in that there is a submenu name "about company" when I am doing it save as copy in Azura page builder for my other menu then the image is not displaying on my website. Then I checked the page source. And I found the path of the image is got change and some HTML code is also change after doing save as copy in Azura builder.
Can anyone help me to find the solution?

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for posting your question.  Since you are new here, please take our [tour] while you wait for support.  As for your question, could you please edit your question to show us the expected image path and expected html versus the image path and html that is being generated?  These specific details may help a volunteer to better understand and answer your question.

Comment: Please provide more information as @mickmackusa said, but it seems like Azura Builder isn't passing the image path to your submenu. Check if there's any way to modify/add the path manually.